# Как использовать тип данных Literal в python?

Tags: python

Я хочу, чтобы моя функция принимала только две строки `'male'` и `'female'`. В библиотеке `tkinter` в инициализации класса `Label` есть параметр `justify: Literal['left', 'center', 'right']`(принимает только эти три строки). Как мне использовать тип данных `Literal`?

Comment: Ну почитайте [доки](https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/).

Comment: Ну вот вы уже продемонстрировали готовый пример использования. В чём проблема?

Comment: Использовать точно так же как любую другую аннотацию типа. При исполнении это никак само по себе не проверяется, но IDE, например, вам подсветит, если вы в функцию что-то не то передадите.

Comment: Вопрос фактически не связан с tkinter (не про tkinter), метку повторно удаляю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря какое поведение вы ожидаете от функции. Если просто подсветить и хинт вывести, что аргумент не подходит, то можно обойтись и указанием типов аргументов. Если же вам нужно запретить использование невалидных аргументов в функции, то нужно их проверить и отреагировать. Ниже 3 варианта, как это сделать:

```
from typing import *


def example(justify: Literal['left', 'center', 'right']):
    return justify


def example2(justify):
    valid_list = ['left', 'center', 'right']
    if justify not in valid_list:
        raise TypeError(f'Некорректное значение аргумента: {justify}. Ожидалось {valid_list}')
    return justify


def example3(justify: Literal['left', 'center', 'right']):
    valid_list = ['left', 'center', 'right']
    if justify not in valid_list:
        raise TypeError(f'Некорректное значение аргумента: {justify}. Ожидалось {valid_list}')
    return justify


print(example('another'))  # аргумент подсвечивается в IDE и выдает хинт "Expected type 'Literal['left', 'center', 'right']', got 'Literal['another']' instead"
print(example2('another'))  # выбрасывает исключение с описанием ошибки
print(example3('another'))  # и подсвечивает аргумент и выбрасывает исключение
```

```
another
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex20\PycharmProjects\test\main.py", line 49, in <module>
    print(example2('another'))  # выбрасывает исключение с описанием ошибки
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alex20\PycharmProjects\test\main.py", line 44, in example2
    raise TypeError(f'Некорректное значение аргумента: {justify}. Ожидалось {valid_list}')
TypeError: Некорректное значение аргумента: another. Ожидалось ['left', 'center', 'right']
```

Как видно, в 1 случае невалидный аргумент проходит обработку и функция возвращает значение. Во 2-м и третьем (совмещенном) вариантах выполнение кода останавливается и выводится сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: я хотел узнать что-то вроде, в какой библиотеке этот класс, и по вашему коду понял, что он в модуле `typing`. Спасибо за помощь.